# Solving an integral equation in Python

Tags: python, integral-equations

I have to solve the following equation for $x(i), 0 \leq i \leq 1$:

$$ y(i) = x(i)^{-a} \int_0^1 y(j)x(j) dj \left(\int_0^1 \mathcal A(j) x(j)^{1-a} dj\right)^{-1} \int_i^1 \left( \int_0^x x(j)^{1-a} dj \right)^\frac{a+b}{a-1} A_i^{b - 1} dx $$

where $A_i$ and $y(i)$ are known and I use the short cut

$$ \mathcal A(j) = \int_j^1 A_z^{1 - b} dz$$.

I guess there is no point in trying to solve it symbolically with Sympy. How would I go on solving this numerically using Python? Do I discretize $x(i)$ into 100 or 1000 points and hope to brute force find a solution to the system of equations? Or is there a more clever approach?

Comment: Where is this integral equation from?

Comment: @RazimanT.V. Economics.

Comment: My first idea would be to brute force the equation and use a numerical integration method (like simpson rule or something) and then solve using a fixed point or a secant method.

Comment: @BlaisB Could you evaluate a bit on that? Does that mean you would not explicitely create a vector $X$, but approximate $x(i)$ using some sort of polynomial?

Comment: What I mean is that I would discretize the interval [0 1] and [i 1] into a given amount of point (say 100, 1000, not hard). Then you could carry out all the integrations numerically instead of trying to carry out any analytical procedure. I am not sure what exactly you are trying to solve, do you want to calcul y(i) or find x(i) corresponding to a value of y(i)?

Comment: @BlaisB I want to calculate x(i), the remainder is all known. Solving all the integrations numerically means that I'd solve a system of 100, 1000 equations simultaneously using broyden's method, for example?

Comment: No, it would be mean you would carry out the integration numerically using something like the trapezoidal method and then use a global solver to find the solution. Let me give you an example. Say you know y(i) and you wish to find the corrresponding x(i). You start with an estimate x(i)_0 and you calculate the resulting y(i)_0 by calculating each integral numerically. Then by using the error on y(i)-y(i)_0, you choose a next x(i)_1. This can be via a bissection method, secant method, etc. Then you iterate until x(i)_n+1 =x(i)_n. In theory, this should work, but it might be time consuming.

Comment: @BlaisB But I would have to do that for the whole grid $y(0), ... y(1)$ simultaneously, wouldn't it? Because the other values of $y(-i)$ appear in $y(i)$. That's why I thought I'd have to update all 100 grid points at the same time, instead of going from one point to the next

Comment: I think that could work iteratively if you use the previous value in the integrals. Say you discretize in 1000 points and you solve for $x_i+1$ using the values of $x_i$. You told me you were looking for $x_i$ knowing $y_i$ so in this case your discretization would be on $x_i$.

Comment: @BlaisB Just to be sure: Discretize on $N$ points. You suggest start with a set of guesses $x_i^0$ for all $i$. Then, compute $x_0^1$ using the guesses. Next, compute $x_1^1$ using the guesses, up to $x_N^1$. Instead of using all the $N$ errors jointly for the guesses $x_i^2$ (which is what broyden would do), you suggest to update each discretized point using his own error only.

Comment: This is what I suggest. I do not know the specifics about Broyden, but if you can avoid solving a matrix system, then that is a good thing.